# java: if...else statement might be incorrect in my code

Tags: java

As an output, "Player card" should be outputted with randomly selected suit and value, however it's not with my code.

Is there something missing or I have my if...else statements messed up? I know I can use do...while, but I want to be able to do it with if...else statements.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //A new object, player card for the card suit.
    Card player = new Card();

    //Setting the suit for player card to be displayed randomly
    player.setSuit((int) (Math.random()*4));

    //Setting the value for player card to be displayed randomly 
    player.setValue(1 + (int)(Math.random()*12));

    //A new object, computer card for the card suit
    Card comp = new Card();

    //Setting the suit for computer card to be displayed randomly
    comp.setSuit((int) (Math.random()*4));

    //Setting the value for computer card to be displayed randomly
    comp.setValue(1 + (int)(Math.random()*12));


    if((comp.getValue()== player.getValue()) && (comp.getSuit() == player.getSuit()))
        System.out.println("Player Card: " + player.getValueString() + " of " + player.getSuitString());
        System.out.println("Computer Card: " + comp.getValueString() + " of " + comp.getSuitString());
        if(player.getValue() > comp.getValue())
            System.out.println("Player won!");
        else if(player.getValue() < comp.getValue())
            System.out.println("Computer won!");
        else
            System.out.println("Tie!");
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  What is the output you expect, and what is the output you get?

Comment: "Player Card" will only be printed if the player card and computer card are the same.

Comment: Can you describe the output you are getting?

Comment: You are not using curly brackets in your if/else blocks, which makes it very difficult to follow what's going on. In fact, your indentation suggests different blocks from how the compiler actually interprets your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only outputs the player's and computer's cards if they are exactly the same. Change this:

```
if((comp.getValue()== player.getValue()) && (comp.getSuit() == player.getSuit()))
        System.out.println("Player Card: " + player.getValueString() + " of " + player.getSuitString());
        System.out.println("Computer Card: " + comp.getValueString() + " of " + comp.getSuitString());
        if(player.getValue() > comp.getValue())
            System.out.println("Player won!");
        else if(player.getValue() < comp.getValue())
            System.out.println("Computer won!");
        else
            System.out.println("Tie!");
```

To this:

```
System.out.println("Player Card: " + player.getValueString() + " of " + player.getSuitString());
System.out.println("Computer Card: " + comp.getValueString() + " of " + comp.getSuitString());
if((comp.getValue()== player.getValue()) && (comp.getSuit() == player.getSuit()))
        // handle redrawing cards here
if(player.getValue() > comp.getValue())
    System.out.println("Player won!");
else if(player.getValue() < comp.getValue())
    System.out.println("Computer won!");
else
    System.out.println("Tie!");
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks better:

```
if(comp.getValue() == player.getValue())
    System.out.println("Tie!");
else if(player.getValue() > comp.getValue())
    System.out.println("Player won!");
else if(player.getValue() < comp.getValue())
    System.out.println("Computer won!");
```

Plus, if you don't use brackets (`if { .. } else { .. }`), only the first line below the if statement will be executed in the if.

Answer (score 1):

try using brackets to determine what is in each condition, that way you don't get lost.

Answer (score 0):

The first line after your long `if` condition is only executed if the random card you got for player and comp match, which is unlikely. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

You should probably remove that line altogether (any reasons why it is there?):

```
if((comp.getValue()== player.getValue()) && (comp.getSuit() == player.getSuit()))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your question, you have the if conditions mistaken. As you have them now they will match only if the computer and player cards are exactly the same.

Try something like:

```
 if(comp != null && player != null){
  System.out.println("Player Card: " + player.getValueString() + " of " + player.getSuitString());
  System.out.println("Computer Card: " + comp.getValueString() + " of " + comp.getSuitString());

  if(player.getValue() > comp.getValue())
        System.out.println("Player won!");
    else if(player.getValue() < comp.getValue())
        System.out.println("Computer won!");
    else
        System.out.println("Tie!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't analyze too much but it seems to me that you want some blocks to be inside if but you forgot `{ }` to make those blocks, no?

Answer (score 0):

An If statement will apply to the block of code in curly braces after it

```
if(condition){
thenDoSomething();
thenDoSomethingElse();
}
```

If there is no curly braces, then only the next statement will apply to the If

```
if(condition)
thisWillRunIfConditionIsTrue();
thisWillAlwaysRun();
```

Your code has no curly braces, so the player output will only print when it matches the computers output, while the computers output will always print.

```
     if((comp.getValue()== player.getValue()) && (comp.getSuit() == player.getSuit())) 
            System.out.println("Player Card: " + player.getValueString() + " of " + player.getSuitString());  
            System.out.println("Computer Card: " + comp.getValueString() + " of " + comp.getSuitString());
```

Answer (score 0):

the first 'if' is evaluating as false so the line:

```
System.out.println("Player Card: " + player.getValueString() + " of " + player.getSuitString());
```

is never called (unless both value and suit are equal).

you code look something like this:

```
if((comp.getValue()== player.getValue()) && (comp.getSuit() == player.getSuit())) {

System.out.println("Player Card: " + player.getValueString() + " of " + player.getSuitString());

}

System.out.println("Computer Card: " + comp.getValueString() + " of " + comp.getSuitString());
```

always use curly bracket with 'if' statements.